Puppeteer not working after deployed in render but works on my local machine
I am trying to deploy my API for fetch compatibility details for my website. The API is running perfectly in my local machine I tested several time by postman but when deployed it gives 500 internal error every time.
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapeCompatibility(req, res) {
    try {
    
        const { sign1,sign2 } = req.body;
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        const url = `https://www.horoscope.com/us/games/compatibility/game-love-compatibility.aspx?ZodiacSignSelector_alphastring=${sign1}&PartnerZodiacSignSelector_alphastring=${sign2}`;
        await page.goto(url);

        // Selector for horoscope content might change on the website. Update as needed.
        const compatibilityScore = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.game-compatibility-score').innerText);
        const compatibilityText = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.module-skin p').innerText);
        await browser.close();
        console.log(compatibilityScore);
        console.log(compatibilityText);
        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            data: {compatibilityScore,compatibilityText }
       })
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        return res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message:"Something went wrong"
        })
    }
}

module.exports = { scrapeCompatibility };

This is the error that i am facing
 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npx puppeteer browsers install chrome`) or
 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /opt/render/.cache/puppeteer).
For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
    at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:288:27)
    at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:207:25)
    at ChromeLauncher.computeLaunchArguments (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:89:37)
    at async ChromeLauncher.launch (/opt/render/project/src/server/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:70:28)
    at async scrapeHoroscope (/opt/render/project/src/server/Controllers/Horoscope.js:7:25)```


https://github.com/Panchalparth471/Astroseek-Production the github repo of this code

500 internal error means you should look at your Render logs and see what the error says. Please [edit] the post with the full stack trace as text when you find it. Thanks.

@ggorlen i have checked the logs already nothing is appearing there

It seems impossible that a 500 server error wouldn't be logged by render. I'd check your setup--make sure logging is on, you're looking in the correct place, running the right thing, hitting the right endpoint, etc.

sorry i didnt console log the error.After going through logs i am getting this error Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 123.0.6312.105). This can occur if either

Thanks, that helps. There should be more to the error, but that should be enough to search on: 1, 2, 3. Make you've installed Chrome for starters, with something like npx puppeteer browsers install chrome. Also, it's good to [edit] that error message into the question so it's complete and most helpful for future visitors.
